# Elastic search must not clause not working properly

Tags: json, elasticsearch, search, dsl

I am facing some issue to filter my search query in elastic search using "**must_not**" clause

**Mapping that I have inserted for my index**

```
{
    "monojit": {
        "mappings": {
            "banik": {
                "properties": {
                    "productid": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "priority": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "excludesku": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have inserted below mentioned json data one by one

Sample data 1:

```
   {
        "productid": "MP01212,MP0766,MP865578,MP8656889",
        "excludesku": "98656890,86444326",
        "priority":2,

    }
```

Sample data 2:

```
 {
        "productid": "MP01212",
        "excludesku": "12345642570,32434434,3938463732",
        "priority":1,

    }
```

My query was

```
{ 
   "query":{ 
    "constant_score":{
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [ 
                  {
                   "bool": {
                    "must":{
                        "match": {
                         "productid": "MP01212"
                      }
                    },
                    "must_not":{
                        "match":{
                         "excludesku": "3938463732"
                        }
                    }
                   }  
                  }
                  ]
            }
        }
    }
   }, 
    "sort" : {
       "priority":{
        "order":"asc"
       }
    }
}
```

My query giving me all the hits but I want only "Sample data 1" in result but unfortunately "excludeussid" field is not working. please suggest me.

Comment: is it a typo? you used  `excludesku` in your mapping and indexing doc but using `excludeussid` in query?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja sorry it was typo.

Comment: ok, working on tp provide a fix

Comment: It is working fine if I use exact string of "excludesku" i.e "12345642570,32434434,3938463732" in the query.

Comment: also looks like you are using older version of ES, can you tell which one

Comment: using version 6.4.0.....................................................................................

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211066/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-monojit).